# How can I update a module to a specific version using Drush?

Tags: drush

I am trying to update module entityform 7.x-1.4 to entityform 7.x-2.0-beta4.

The current version of the entityform module is 7.x-2.0-rc4. But I don't want to update at this version.

Can we update module at specific version using drush?

Answer (score 9):

By default, `drush pm-update` will update Drupal core and all enabled projects to the latest recommended releases. The optional project argument allows you to provide a list of installed projects to update, thereby limiting the scope of the update.

You can also pass a specific version of Drupal core as a project argument and Drush will limit the upgrade to that version of core (and core only, unless you pass other projects along as arguments.)

```bash
drush pm-update entityform-7.x-2.0-rc4
```